# array to hash using pattern matching

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

@ops array contains the below content

```
status: 0
duration: done
name: NA:/ny/wdc
system: legacy
type: new
```

I am trying to make a hash using below

```
foreach my @op (@ops) {
    my ($k, $v) = $op =~ /^(.*): (.*)$/;
    $r{$k}     = $v;
}
```

But its not working, Please suggest

Comment: "Its not working" is not a very good way to describe a problem. In fact, its completely useless. When I run this code I get the error `Missing $ on loop variable`. Is that what is "not working" with your code?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, that should be typo, my intention is to  make a hash like ($k, $v <- a: b)

Comment: You should never post code that you have not been running, it is inconsiderate towards those who donate their time and knowledge towards helping you solve your problem.

Comment: Apologies, In future will post correct information, Thanks for the advise!

Comment: Don't apologize, fix your question. Make the code runnable and demonstrating your problem. Include the errors you get, and show how `@ops` is generated and/or what it contains, preferably using `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@ops;` And say in what way your code does not work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated in what way it fails to work, but `foreach my @op (@ops)` should be `foreach my $op (@ops)`.  You're taking one thing at a time from the array and a single item is a scalar (`$`), not an array (`@`).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, that should be typo, my intention is to make a hash like ($k, $v <- a: b)

Answer (score 1):

The loop variable in a foreach loop must be a single scalar. Change `@op` to `$op`:

```
foreach my $op (@ops) {
```

You could also simplify your code to `my %r = map /^([^:]+): (.*)/, @ops`, as a regex match in list context returns a list of captures.